# What is the sum of only half the exponential terms that give the Dirac comb?

Tags: fourier-series, distribution-theory

The following infinite sum of exponential terms gives a [Dirac comb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb):
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{i n x} = 2 \pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x - 2 \pi n) $$
Of course the sum doesn't strictly converge, but only in the same sense in which the Dirac delta-function is defined.

What is the result of a semi-infinite sum of such terms?
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{i n x} =~? $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

(1) write the semi-infinite sum in the following way
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{i n x} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{i n x}
+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \mathop{\rm sgn}(n) e^{i n x} - \frac{1}{2}.$$

The first summand is the Dirac-comb. So your question reduces to figuring out what the second term equals to...

(2) [Lagrange's trigonometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange.27s_trigonometric_identities) might help there...

Comment: Got it - thanks!